Dependency Injection works in API, but failing in a .NET 8 console application
I am trying to utilize a library written to add Sharepoint functionality. Here is how the SharepointClient class is constructed in the library.
public class SharePointClient : ISharePointClient
{
    private readonly SafeILogger<SharePointClient> _logger;
    private readonly SharePointClientConfig _clientConfig;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public SharePointClient(SafeILogger<SharePointClient> logger, 
    IOptions<SharePointClientConfig> clientConfig)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _clientConfig = clientConfig.Value ?? throw new 
         ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientConfig));

        _graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();
    }
}

The method to add the utility library looks like this
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSharePointUtils(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<SharePointClientConfig>()
            .BindConfiguration("SharePointClientConfig")
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        services.AddScoped<ISharePointClient, SharePointClient>();

        return services;
    }
}

I have a FileUploader class that takes the SharepointClient class in the constructor which I need to instantiate through dependency injection.
public class FileUploader : IFileUploader
{        
     private readonly ISharePointClient _sharePointClient;

     public FileUploader(ISharePointClient sharePointClient)
     {
         _sharePointClient = sharePointClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sharePointClient));
     }

     public async Task UploadFile(string fileSourceFilePath, string fileName)
     {
         await _sharePointClient.UploadFileToDrive("TestPath", "Test",
                                                   fileSourceFilePath, fileName);
     }
}

Now I have used the utility in a .NET 8 API project and the DI works perfectly.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSafeILogger();
builder.Services.AddSharePointUtils();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();

But when I am trying to implement it in a .NET 8 console app, I get this error:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSafeILogger();
services.AddScoped<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();
services.AddSharePointUtils();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var fileUploader = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFileUploader>();


'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'1[Common.SharePoint.Utils.SharePointClient]' while attempting to activate 'Common.Api.Logging.SafeILogger'1[Common.SharePoint.Utils.SharePointClient]'.'

The method AddSafeILogger() resolves this dependency in the API project, but it is failing to resolve the dependency in Console application.
Here is the AddSafeILogger:
namespace Common.Api.Logging;

public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSafeILogger(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(SafeILogger<>));
        return services;
    }
}

SafeILogger is a class inherited from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Ilogger
I am not sure why the DI implementation is working for API application, but in the console app when I am trying to instantiate FileUploader by calling GetRequiredService method, I am getting the mentioned dependency error. DI for other custom classes work fine in the console app.

Does SafeILogger have any dependencies that need to be satisfied that you might not have registered?

Please explain what SafeLogger<T> is and why you're using it. If it isn't an interface type then you'll run into problems because only interface-types support generic-type covariance, which ILogger<T> takes advantage of.

So your SafeILogger service depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging being registered - but nowhere in any of the code you've posted does it show you  calling MEL's ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging() method - whereas inside ASP.NET Web-API that will call AddLogging for you behind-the-scenes.

@Dai I already tried .AddLogging(), it throws "No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' has been registered"

@Tanveer-Ibn-Haresh you explicitly removed the host that set up logging. In a console application use Host.CreateDefaultBuilder

@Tanveer-Ibn-Haresh So then you need to register Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration...

You're registering scoped services, so you should create a service scope to access them. using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope(); scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<>();

You can use the same hosting infrastructure in a console application by using the same Generic Host :
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSafeILogger();
builder.Services.AddSharePointUtils();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();

var app=builder.Build()

var client=app.Services.GetRequiredService<ISharePointClient>();
...


What worked was HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
Thanks.

The issue you are facing because the console application does not configure the ILogger dependency as it is done automatically in a Web API project. you must configure it explicitly.
// Configure logging
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
        .AddTransient(typeof(SafeILogger<>), typeof(SafeILogger<>));

// Add your services
services.AddSafeILogger();


I tried something like this before, I get "No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' has been registered"

@Tanveer-Ibn-Haresh What dependencies does SafeILogger require? You'll need to make sure these are added to the service collection as well. I'm assuming from your comment it needs an IConfiguration instance.
